# adb push in a script

Tags: android, bash

I have a simple bash script to push an executable to the android and then remove it.

```
#!/bin/bash
adb push CMakeBuild_Android_armv8/Out/Release/exec /data/local/tmp/exec
adb shell rm data/local/tmp/exec
```

This is saved as 'adb_push.sh'. I made sure that this is an executable via chmod.

```
chmod +x adb_push.sh
```

But when I run this script in the Cygwin `./adb_push.sh`, I get an error that there is no such directory.

```
CMakeBuild_Android_armv8/Out/Release/exec: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 62.5 MB/s (7302616 bytes in 0.111s)
rm: data/local/tmp/exec: No such file or directory
```

Is there any obvious steps that I am missing in creating a bash script or is there any error in what I am doing?

Any hint or comment would be highly appreciated.

ADB version:

```
$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 31.0.0-7110759
Installed as C:\platform-tools_r31.0.0-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

Disclaimer: I already tried putting the source and destination path in quotes, it did not work for me. Also tried the same with a .wav file instead of an executable and I get the same error which lead me to believe that something's not right in the bash script.

Comment: The first command is succeeding. Only the second command is failing. Are you trying to remove the file you just pushed? If `adb shell` doesn't start at the root (`/`), then the destination path you supply in the first command (`/data/local/tmp/exec`) is different from the path you supply in the second command (`data/local/tmp/exec`, note the missing slash at the beginning). I'm gonna guess `adb shell` starts a shell in some user's home directory, not `/`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But, I now have a follow up question. How do I start my adb shell at the root?

Comment: I added an answer. See Option 2 for "How do I start my adb shell at the root?"

Comment: I had the same problem in WSL / Windows10. An `adb push` worked from the command line, but the exact same command failed in a bash script ("adb: error: failed to get feature set: no devices/emulators found"). I noticed that `adb` had been aliased to `adb.exe`, so changed the script to call `adb.exe` directly, and that fixed the problem. Strange!

Answer (score 1):

## Your second command assumes the working directory is the root `/`. It appears this assumption is false.

The first command is succeeding. Only the second command is failing.
If adb shell doesn't start at the root (`/`), then the destination path you supply in the first command (`/data/local/tmp/exec`) is different from the path you supply in the second command (`data/local/tmp/exec`, note the missing slash at the beginning).

I'm gonna guess `adb shell` on your device starts a shell in some user's home directory, not `/`.

### Option 1: Use absolute file path

You can fix this by giving the full absolute file path in your second command:

```
adb shell rm /data/local/tmp/exec
```

### Option 2: Change directories before your command

Alternatively, you can change to the root directory before running the command. `adb shell` (as of version 31.0.0-7110759) does not have the ability to set the working directory, but you can do this *inside* the shell by adding a `cd` before your `rm`. Note that the command must now be quoted to prevent your local shell from interpreting the list operator `&&`:

```
adb shell 'cd / && rm data/local/tmp/exec'
```

**Note:** The `adb shell` default working directory may vary by device or ROM. On my stock Pixel 3 it does in fact start at the root:

```
$ adb shell pwd
/
```